# Airflow dags - reporting of the runtime for tracking purposes

Tags: statistics, runtime, airflow, metrics, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to find a way to capture the dag  stats - i.e run time (start time, end time), status, dag id, task id, etc for various dags and their task in a separate table

- found the default logs which goes to elasticsearch/kibana, but not a simple way to pull the required logs from there back to the s3 table.
- building a separate process to load those logs in s3 will have replicated data and also there will be too much data to scan and filter as tons of other system-related logs are generated as well.
- adding a function to each dag - would have to modify each dag

what other possibilities are to get it don't efficiently, of any other airflow inbuilt feature can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Ad Hoc Query available in Apache airflow.

This option is available at Data Profiling -> Ad Hoc Query and select airflow_db

If you wish to get DAG statistics such as start_time,end_time etc you can simply query in the below format

```
select start_date,end_date from dag_run where dag_id = 'your_dag_name'
```

The above query returns start_time and end_time details of the DAG for all the DAG runs. If you wish to get details for a particular run then you can add another filter condition like below

```
select start_date,end_date from dag_run where dag_id = 'your_dag_name' and execution_date = '2021-01-01 09:12:59.0000' ##this is a sample time
```

You can get this execution_date from tree or graph views. Also you can get other stats like id,dag_id,execution_date,state,run_id,conf as well.

You can also refer to [https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/profiling.html#:~:text=Part%20of%20being%20productive%20with,application%20letting%20you%20visualize%20data](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/profiling.html#:%7E:text=Part%20of%20being%20productive%20with,application%20letting%20you%20visualize%20data). link for more details.

Comment: Thanks, however on Airflow2, they changed this feature for Data Profiling -> Ad Hoc Query to DAG run etc, i need to pull those details in a separate table, so trying to access via dag.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention do you need this information real time or in batches.

Since you do not want to use ES logs either, you can try [airflow metrics](http://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/metrics.html), if it suits your need.

However pulling this information from database is not efficient, in any case but it still is an option if you are not looking for real time data collection.